# Update immediately after delete data

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      this.state = { 
      users:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/employees`)
    .then(res => {
      const users = res.data;
      this.setState({ users });

    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Main users= {this.state.users}/>
        <Form/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Main extends Component{
  state = {
    id: ''
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ id: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/employees/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log("this is" + res.data);
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Person Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me why after the Axios delete request, how I can render the new state in the `users` array from App component?

In the App component, I am trying to make `this.state.users` as a props to send it to the Form component. My guess is put `this.setState({users: res.data})`. The delete request is fine with 200, but I need to refresh the page to get the new result. How can I update immediatly?

```
// this is a json object
"employees": [
{
  "id": 8,
  "first_name": "Lteve",
  "last_name": "Palmer",
  "email": "steve@codingthesmartway.com"
},
```

Comment: What do you want? Your state to return to it's default state? Depending on the use case, you might want to do optimistic loading, where you set the state BEFORE sending the async request, then catching errors and resetting the data if the delete fails.

Comment: the delete request is fine with 200, but I need to refresh the page to get the new result. How can I update immediatly?

Comment: By deleting the object from state instead of waiting for the delete request to re-fill state. Which it doesn't do now--you're attempting to manage state in two places, which is almost never a good idea. The delete should happen in the parent component, not the child--and the only thing you need to check from the `delete` API call is that it was actually deleted so you can reconcile your client and server state.

Comment: @DaveNewton so the delete request stuff, you suggest to keep it on the App component, only the form stuff keep it in on the Form component?

Comment: Where do you list the users object in Main that you receive from App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave mentions in a comment you want to have single responsibility for state between components.

This topic is also discussed in the blog post [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), where one solution to your problem is to have Main "report back" to App in order to update state. So either App passes down a `onDeleteUser` function, or a callback for when a user is removed, such as `onUserWasDeleted`.

The latter can be done with the least amount of changes to your code I suppose.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onUserWasDeleted = this.onUserWasDeleted.bind(this);
  }

  onUserWasDeleted(userId) {
    // remove user that was successfully removed
    this.setState({ users: this.state.users.filter(user => user.id !== userId) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Main
        users={this.state.users}
        // pass down a callback to Main
        onUserDeleted={this.onUserWasDeleted}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Main extends Component {
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/employees/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log("this is" + res.data);
      // call our callback function in App
      this.props.onUserWasDeleted(this.state.id);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/cmsio/pen/gyJvgb. Can you please take a look my code pen. I change it to your way. However, after the setstate trigger (onUserWasDeleted(userId)). I console.log(this.state.users), it still return the same aways.

Comment: That's because `setState` is asynchronous. There's a callback available which is called afterwards, `setState({ users: [] }, () => console.log(this.state.users))` if you want to see the result after the state was applied. You can read more about that topic on [State and Lifecycle - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: Thank you so much, I figure it out why it could not update since I compared number and string. it causes them can not be compared